# MIPS program gets stuck on nested function

Tags: assembly, mips

My program seems to get stuck on box_1, after the jal instruction for Ch. I figure it's got to do with $ra getting overwritten. How do I fix this?

The program is supposed to be a simple bitcoin miner. Here is the diagram:

[LINK](http://static.righto.com/images/bitcoin/SHA_2.svg-w400.png)

I'm using [this](http://www.righto.com/2014/09/mining-bitcoin-with-pencil-and-paper.html) article.

I figure that the way of solving this might have to do with saving $ra on the stack but that seems a bit unpractical and inefficient? Likely I am doing something wrong.

```
    .data

    A:      .word   0x87564C0C
    B:      .word   0xF1369725
    C:      .word   0x82E6D493
    D:      .word   0x63A6B509
    E:      .word   0xDD9EFF54
    F:      .word   0xE07C2655
    G:      .word   0xA41F32E7
    H:      .word   0xC7D25631
    W:      .word   0x6534EA14
    K:      .word   0xC67178F2



.text
.globl  main

main:

    li  $s0,0   #loop counter
    li  $s1,64  #loop limit

    main_loop:
        bge $s0,$s1,end_main_loop

            jal box_0
            move    $a0,$v0 #save return value in $a0 to be used as argument by box_1

            jal box_1
            move    $a0,$v0 #

            jal box_2
            move    $a0,$v0 #
            move    $s2,$a0 #will be necessary for the input of box_4 later

            jal box_3
            move    $s3,$v0 #Will be assigned to E later

            jal box_4
            move    $a0,$v0 #

            jal box_5


            ###Assignments

            lw  $a0,G
            la  $a1,H
            sw  $a0,($a1) #Old G goes into new H

            lw  $a0,F
            la  $a1,G
            sw  $a0,($a1)   #Old F goes into new G

            lw  $a0,E
            la  $a1,F
            sw  $a0,($a1)   #Old E goes into new F

            #

            la  $a1,E
            sw  $s3,($a1)   #Output of box_3 goes into new E

            #

            lw  $a0,C
            la  $a1,D
            sw  $a0,($a1)   #Old C goes into new D

            lw  $a0,B
            la  $a1,C

            sw  $a0,($a1)   #Old B goes into new C

            lw  $a0,A
            la  $a1,B

            sw  $a0,($a1)   #Old A goes into new B

            #

            la  $a0,A
            sw  $v0,($a0)   #Output of box_5 goes into new A


            addi    $s0,$s0,1   #increment loop counter





    end_main_loop:

        li  $v0, 10          # terminate program
        syscall


.text
.globl red_boxes

red_boxes:

box_0:

    lw  $t0,W
    lw  $t1,K

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1 #Wt + Kt

    move    $v0,$t1

    jr  $ra


box_1: 

    move    $t0,$a0     #output of box_0

    jal Ch 
    move    $t1,$v0

    lw  $t3,H

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1
    addu    $t3,$t0,$t3

    move    $v0,$t3

    jr  $ra

box_2:

    move    $t0,$a0     #output of box_1
    #move   $t1,$a1     #output of Sigma1

    jal Sigma1

    move    $t1,$v0

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1

    move    $v0,$t0

    jr  $ra

box_3:

    move    $t0,$a0     #output of box_2

    lw  $t1,D

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1

    move    $v0,$t0

    jr  $ra

box_4:

    move    $t0,$a0     #output of box_2 <----!!

    #move   $t1,$a1     #output of Ma

    jal Ma
    move    $t1,$v0

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1

    move    $v0,$t0

    jr  $ra

box_5:

    move    $t0,$a0     #output of box_4
    #move   $t1,$a1     #output of Sigma0

    jal Sigma0 
    move    $t1,$v0

    addu    $t0,$t0,$t1

    move    $v0,$t0

    jr  $ra

.text
.globl op_boxes

op_boxes:

Ch:
#           (G&!E) || (F&E)

            lw  $t0,E
            lw  $t1,F
            lw  $t2,G


            and $t1,$t1,$t0 #(F&E)
            not $t0,$t0     #!E
            and $t2,$t2,$t0 #(G&!E)

            or  $t0,$t1,$t2 #(G&!E) || (F&E)

            move    $v0,$t0

            jr  $ra

Sigma1:

            lw  $t0,E

            ror $t1,$t0,6   #rotates E to the right by 6 bits
            ror $t2,$t0,11  # '''           by 11 bits
            ror $t3,$t0,25  # '''           by 25 bits

            addu    $t2,$t2,$t1 # A->6 + A->11
            addu    $t3,$t3,$t2 # (A->6 + A->11) + A->25

            li  $t1,1

            and $t1,$t3,$t1

            move    $v0,$t1

            jr  $ra

Ma:

#           majority = (A&B) | (B&C)   

            lw  $t0,A                      
            lw  $t1,B
            lw  $t2,C

            or $t3, $t0, $t2
            and $t1, $t1, $t3
            and $v0, $t0, $t2

            or $v0, $t1, $v0

            jr  $ra

Sigma0:

#Same as Sigma0 but shifted by different values
            lw  $t0,A

            ror $t1,$t0,2
            ror $t2,$t0,13
            ror $t3,$t0,22

            add $t2,$t2,$t1
            add $t3,$t3,$t2

            li  $t1,1

            and $t1,$t3,$t1

            move    $v0,$t1

            jr  $ra
```

Also, I have used addu instead of add because sometimes I get an overflow. Is this correct? The article doesn't say anything about overflows.

Comment: Yes, the standard practice is to save `$ra` on the stack. If you don't care about conventions you can of course figure out an efficient register allocation scheme. For functions called from one place only, you can even jump back directly (not recommended).

Comment: @Jester Got it. The program still doesn't work like it should though. The value of A isn't being changed for some reason. Here it is if you want to take a look https://pastebin.com/JFa4waQw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> saving $ra on the stack but that seems a bit unpractical and inefficient?

If you know exactly what registers Ch (and all its callee's, here none), then you can save the `$ra` away in one of those registers instead of on the stack to save a cycle here and there.

If you were using RISC V, you could use an alternate register for for the return address when calling `Ch`, and then by avoiding `$ra` here, wouldn't need to preserve `$ra` at all.

---

A couple of approaches if you really want to optimize the code:

One is to develop program-wide register assignments, so that you don't have to keep loading and storing those global variables, instead just manipulating registers.

(This can be hard to do if either the program gets really large, or, you also want to mix calls having compiler generated C code — as the compiler won't necessarily know about your program-wide register assignments.  However, if you write it as a subroutine called by C but doesn't call C back — only returns to C — you can still to the whole subroutine register assignments.)

Another approach would be to inline all the methods — taking a quick glance it doesn't look like there's much reuse by invocation, so such inlining seems indicated.

Both approaches can be combined.

---

Yes, `addu` is appropriate when we don't care about overflow.  It produces the same bit patterns as `add` but simply forgoes the overflow check.